# Sink faucet only flows when barely open

Tags: plumbing, sink, water-pressure, valve

I closed the hot water valve under my bathroom sink and reopened it last night, and since then I'm seeing a strange problem. If I barely turn on the faucet on hot I get water flow, but if I open the faucet more the water stops (and I hear what sounds like some shaking in the line under the sink).

I closed the valve again, unhooked the water line from the faucet, and opened the valve with the water line running into a bucket - nothing came out at all. I reconnected the line to the faucet and as before, I could get water flowing as long as I kept the faucet barely open.

Any thoughts on what it could be? I read about floodsafe hoses and thought it could be something like that, but the water line appears to be simple rubber. Could there be an auto shutoff valve somewhere that is preventing hot water flow when there isn't enough resistance?

Comment: This is confusing. You use the words "sink," "faucet," "tap," and "valve"...and it's not clear what you're talking about. You might be referring only to the stopcock underneath the sink, or perhaps to the faucet or tap on top that one turns to get water to wash hands. "Hose" is also imprecise; I think you're referring to the water line that runs from the stopcock at the wall up to the faucet on top. Clarifying will make it more likely that answers or comments are useful to you.

Comment: The shutoff valve under the sink may be defective. If it's the multi-turn type that has a rubber washer, the washer may have broken down and is partially blocking the supply line. If that's the case you may also have fragements of rubber in the faucet valve causing this problem. I've seen it before.

Comment: Hardly that unclear. It would be useful to remove the hose (which is clearly the flexible waterline between the stopcock and the faucet) completely from the stopcock and place a bucket below, and a cup above to direct water back into the bucket, and have some towels handy for the water that escapes, and see what happens when the stopcock is opened without the hose attached.

Comment: You can close the valve and disconnect the flex tube to the faucet inlet and point it into a bucket and open the valve to see if you have good flow there.  If you do, you can focus on the faucet.  If the faucet is plugged, you may be able to unclog it without disassembly by replacing the strainer with a cut plastic sheet to block it and open hot and cold handles to back flow through the hot cartridge.  Naturally you'd need a catch bucket.

Comment: It would help immensely if you were to [edit] your post to include a couple of pictures clearly labeling the pieces you're talking about in your terms so that others know _exactly_ what you mean.